# the following query is resulting in PG::OutOfMemory error when I run this on 2000+ records at night

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to determine if I just need to upgrade out postgres plan, or if theres is a way to improve this query im running in rails at night on 2000+ records.

```
  values =
      self.users.pluck(:id).map { |s| "(#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(s)})" }.join(',')

    <<-SQL
        select behavior_translations.anchor, habit_translations.name habitName, answers.teamResponds teamResponds, answers.teamAverage teamAverage, answers.companyAverage companyAverage
        from behaviors
        JOIN behavior_translations ON behaviors.id = behavior_translations.behavior_id AND behavior_translations.locale = '#{
      I18n.locale.to_s
    }'
        join habits on behaviors.habit_id = habits.id
        JOIN habit_translations ON habits.id = habit_translations.habit_id AND habit_translations.locale = '#{
      I18n.locale.to_s
    }'
        join engagement_questions on engagement_questions.behavior_id = behaviors.id
        join (
            select answers.answerable_id, count(answers.id) filter (where answers.respondent_id IN (#{
      values
    })) teamResponds, avg(answers.response) filter (where answers.respondent_id IN (#{
      values
    })) teamAverage, avg(answers.response) filter (where answers.respondent_id NOT IN (#{
      values
    })) companyAverage
        from answers
        where answers.answerable_type = 'EngagementQuestion' AND answers.response IN (0, 0.5, 1) and answers.created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '90 days' 
        group by answers.answerable_id
        ) answers on answers.answerable_id = engagement_questions.id
            where behaviors.tenant_id = '#{Multitenancy.current}'
        SQL
```

I have read of people having issues with things like prepared_statements in rails with ActiveRecord causing PG::OOM errors, but im not even sure if this is the cause of the OOM error. I have been trying to recreate this OOM error in our staging environment to better identify the cause, its not the number of connections, because we dont come anywhere near our limit of 200 when running this with sidekiq, but when i run the task that uses the above query in staging (which generates the OOM error in production), it runs fine. This is troubling. Any help would be appreciated!

update: here is the output of EXPLAIN with psql:

```
  [["Merge Join  (cost=136505.37..146839.47 rows=944 width=114)"],
   ["  Merge Cond: (engagement_questions.id = answers.answerable_id)"],
   ["  ->  Sort  (cost=199.08..199.14 rows=23 width=106)"],
   ["        Sort Key: engagement_questions.id"],
   ["        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=121.87..198.56 rows=23 width=106)"],
   ["              Join Filter: (behaviors.habit_id = habit_translations.habit_id)"],
   ["              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=121.59..188.90 rows=23 width=116)"],
   ["                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=121.31..177.11 rows=23 width=100)"],
   ["                          Join Filter: (behaviors.id = behavior_translations.behavior_id)"],
   ["                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=121.03..150.39 rows=23 width=64)"],
   ["                                Hash Cond: (engagement_questions.behavior_id = behaviors.id)"],
   ["                                ->  Seq Scan on engagement_questions  (cost=0.00..26.58 rows=1058 width=32)"],
   ["                                ->  Hash  (cost=119.19..119.19 rows=147 width=32)"],
   ["                                      ->  Index Scan using index_behaviors_on_tenant_id on behaviors  (cost=0.28..119.19 rows=147 width=32)"],
   ["                                            Index Cond: ((tenant_id)::text = 'tenant_id'::text)"],
   ["                          ->  Index Scan using index_behavior_translations_on_behavior_id on behavior_translations  (cost=0.28..1.15 rows=1 width=84)"],
   ["                                Index Cond: (behavior_id = engagement_questions.behavior_id)"],
   ["                                Filter: ((locale)::text = 'en'::text)"],
   ["                    ->  Index Only Scan using habits_pkey on habits  (cost=0.28..0.51 rows=1 width=16)"],
   ["                          Index Cond: (id = behaviors.habit_id)"],
   ["              ->  Index Scan using index_habit_translations_on_habit_id on habit_translations  (cost=0.28..0.41 rows=1 width=38)"],
   ["                    Index Cond: (habit_id = habits.id)"],
   ["                    Filter: ((locale)::text = 'en'::text)"],
   ["  ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=136306.29..146088.30 rows=43403 width=40)"],
   ["        Group Key: answers.answerable_id"],
   ["        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=136306.29..144876.81 rows=56044 width=88)"],
   ["              Workers Planned: 2"],
   ["              ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=135306.27..137407.92 rows=28022 width=88)"],
   ["                    Group Key: answers.answerable_id"],
   ["                    ->  Sort  (cost=135306.27..135376.32 rows=28022 width=56)"],
   ["                          Sort Key: answers.answerable_id"],
   ["                          ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on answers  (cost=8425.91..133236.24 rows=28022 width=56)"],
   ["                                Recheck Cond: ((answerable_type)::text = 'EngagementQuestion'::text)"],
   ["                                Filter: ((response = ANY ('{0,0.5,1}'::double precision[])) AND (created_at > (now() - 'P90D'::interval)))"],
   ["                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_answers_on_answerable_type_and_answerable_id  (cost=0.00..8409.09 rows=642755 width=0)"],
   ["                                      Index Cond: ((answerable_type)::text = 'EngagementQuestion'::text)"]]>
```

Comment: You are joining together 6 tables.  Which of them has 2000+ records?

Comment: Was the plan you have collected in the environment where it would error out if run for real?

Comment: Please show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` taken from the environment where the query succeeds.

Comment: I don't know what `PG::OOM` is.  Who ran out of memory, ruby, the PostgreSQL server, or the PostgreSQL client?  What is the full error message?  Look in the db server's log file.

Comment: i ended up totally removing the caching operation each night, and just optimized the query by adding additional "and record.tenant_id = '#{Multitenancy.current}'" clauses within each joins statement where i was seeing high costs in EXPLAIN, which brought the average costs of the operations within the query down by around 10x, and the transaction time for the query went from 3.485 ms to 0.09ms. So i ended up not needing caching at all. My bad! I was performing this query on 2,000 records each night, to update a data field with this data. Each of these adjoining tables has > 100,000 records.